# Initialize RDP user, only via FTP

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2, ftp, rdp

I have a rather unique issue, and was wondering if there's a simple solution to this that I am failing to find.

I have a Windows Server 2012 instance running remotely, that I have no physical access to. As of yesterday morning I had full control of it via RDP and via FTP.

Yesterday evening I removed Active Directory services and such demoted the domain controller. During this process I changed the password and made a note of the changed password.

Now the server is rebooted, I cannot get access via RDP. I just get a bad credentials error response.

I still have root FTP access, however, is there some way I can regain RDP access using only FTP?

Answer (score 1):

No.

Filler words for length restriction.

Comment: Is there a way I can change the domain RDP tries to connect to? It defaults to AD\Administrator, but obviously with AD disabled that is not going to work.

Comment: Have you tried to connect to the local administrator, e.g. `DC\Administrator` where `DC` is the server name or just plain `Administrator`?

Comment: Yes, but with me having demoted a domain controller yesterday I think that may have had an adverse effect. I can still see all of the users via ftp, and all of the services are still running.

Comment: Welcome to serverfault. Your post may answer the question. But for better understanding some more explanations are needed. Otherwise the answer may become flagged and deleted ;-)